# Problem with save image file in src

Tags: php, image, src

In image.php, the code likes:

```
header("Content-Type:image/png");
$file = "img.png";
readfile($file);
```

In other file, the code is:

```
<img src="image.php">
```

when I right-click from browser to *Save Image As*, it defaults to save as *image.php*.  I would like to save it as *img.png*, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just add this header to your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished through the use of URL rewriting.

In your .htaccess, add something like this (assuming mod_rewrite is enabled and you're on Apache):

```
RewriteRule ^image.png$ /image.php [L]
```

Your HTML changes with the file name to:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

Comment: The image is generated by PHP file.

Comment: Correct. The URL rewrite maps 'image.png' to 'image.php'... image.php is getting called here.